# Error 'CBabstract' not found

Tags: document-classes, document-configuration, documentclass

I am trying to use document class

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{CBabstract}
```

but I have the following error:
File 'CBSabstract.cls' not found.

Could you please help?

Comment: It is not a standard class I have not got it and neither will most other people. Check whatever documentation that told you to use `documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{CBabstract}` should tell you where to find that local class file.

Comment: note that your code fragment says `CBabstract` but your error message says `CBSabstract`  is one of these a typo (extra `S`) and you intended the other? (neither name is a class in the standard distributions)

Comment: It is a non-standard class, so you need to download it and put it somewhere that LaTeX can find it, for example in the same folder as your `.tex` file. Maybe it is http://www.biomath.bg/2014/CBabstract.cls?